# Is there a way I can import relationship between elements in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a number of elements for a given entity. For example I have an entity called "Person" and it has a number of associations/dependencies with elements such as "Age", "Sex", etc. Is there a way I can import these from a CSV file?

The structure in the CSV file looks as follows;

```
Person   Age
Person   Sex
Person   Location
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scripting interface should allow you to do what you need to do.  If you go to Tools->Scripting and then open the EAScriptLib there is a JScript-CSV library with lots of helper function for CSV input and output.

Comment: To get some inspiration have a look at my [Simple VBA Excel to EA importer](http://bellekens.com/2013/04/30/simple-vba-excel-to-ea-importer-v3/). This excel file with vba macro's imports classes, attributes and the glossary. Importing connectors is pretty similar to this.