# Sparx EA - Importing relationships or SQL query to modify connection table

Tags: javascript, mysql, vbscript, enterprise-architect

This is an add on from the following questions: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691982/is-there-a-way-i-can-import-relationship-between-elements-in-enterprise-architec)

I am about to upload a couple thousand requirements into EA Sparx however then to setup the relationships we would have to do so one by one and would take someone around a week to do. Therefor we would like to import the relationships if possible.

From the answers I have found online we can either use a script to import or use a script to alter the database.

I have created a VB script that will edit table data but not ADD TO a table.

Does anyone happen to know an import script? we already have the relationships aligned on an Excel sheet.

Comment: I have tried to use the import/export csv script already in sparx but am unsure how to alter for a relationship as the current script goes from the 'type' (e.g. requirement, package) which does not have a corresponding relationship option. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are a couple of threads on Sparx' forum that deal with importing relationships. I know the search is a PITA, but....

Comment: E.g. this: http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1362567428/1#1

Answer (score 1):

Creating new connectors is best done in code using `EA.Element.Connectors.AddNew()` and not directly in the database because then the EA API will do the hard work and you can be sure of the result.

To get some inspiration have a look at my [Simple VBA Excel to EA importer](http://bellekens.com/2013/04/30/simple-vba-excel-to-ea-importer-v3/). This excel file with vba macro's imports classes, attributes and the glossary.

Importing connectors is pretty similar to this.

Comment: Thank you Geert, I actually downloaded it yesterday! I have not hada chance to have a deep look into it but will do so now :). Thanks.

Comment: Hi Geert, great product thank you very much. I am struggling to know which part of the ExcelImporter code to edit and add it the EA.Element.Connectors.AddNew() function. Can I please ask you to provide some more info?....once again I appreciate your help so far and you have a great product.

Comment: Check this [EA forum topic](http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1431486490) I've added a code sample there.

Comment: Thank you Geert, that was mine as well. I have included what I managed to get working. For everyone else looking at this question please see the link in Geert's comment :)